# Navigation Bar turns black when new VC is being pushed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently having trouble fixing this behaviour. I have a run-of-the-mill view controller embedded into a navigationController. When I push a new VC into it, the navigationBar becomes pitch black.

[image: navigationController black]

I've tried a few things, such as setting `translucent` to `false`, changing `barTintColor` to `UIColor.whiteColor()`, and `setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)`. But to no avail. Any help is appreciated!